# How to correctly modify the following "switch" statement to get the expected output value

Tags: c

/I saw that the result of `k` was 4 through argument watches, but the final result was 123 after the program finished. Why is that?/

/Thanks for answers. 
I have made clear what i was confused before.
In fact ,this is a question asking the output in an exam .I was wrong in the exam because i thought the output was 1 ,but the right answer is 123.
Maybe it's the reason that makes unclear instruction./

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    switch (k)
    {
    case 1:   printf("%d", k++);
    case 2:   printf("%d", k++);
    case 3:   printf("%d", k++);
        break;
    default:  printf("Full!");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't said what the expected output is, nor the input for a given output.

Comment: I encourage you to check the result of _scanf_ ( `if (scanf(..) == 1) { swich..` ) to be sure he user enter a valid _int_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *final result* in your code: `k` is not used after the `switch` so its value in the debugger is meaningless.

You can modify the code to print the final value of `k` and will see that `1`, `2` and `3` get converted to `4`, all other values remaining unchanged.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    switch (k) {
      case 1:   printf("%d\n", k++);
      case 2:   printf("%d\n", k++);
      case 3:   printf("%d\n", k++);
        break;
      default:  printf("Full!\n");
        break;
    }
    printf("%d\n", k);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two wrongs in your code:

- Why is `k++` other than `k`?
- It has no `break` for every `case`

Because of these errors, you will get `123` if you input `1`.

I guess that you only want to print the inputs, so the corrected code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int k;
    scanf("%d", &k);
    switch (k)
    {
    case 1:   printf("%d", k);
        break;
    case 2:   printf("%d", k);
        break;
    case 3:   printf("%d", k);
        break;
    default:  printf("Full!");
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback :)  I didn't want the break on purpose.